# erreichen sein or haben?

Tags: standard-german, swiss-standard-german

I know that sein is used when there is transformation. I have read that "erreichen" has "haben" as it's auxiliary verb.

> Aufbauend auf der Idee, dass Bildung nicht ohne Erziehung zu erreichen ist, versuchte die Lehrerin, die Eltern zu mehr Engagement für die Schule zu bewegen.

How come we have "erreichen ist" here and not "erreichen hat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the verb *sein* is not an auxiliary verb, it is a full verb. And *erreichen* is part of a construction called *"zu + Infinitiv":*

> Bildung ist wichtig.
> Bildung ist zu erreichen.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I could not think in that way. Next time onwards, I will do it better. Thank you again :)